# Making Request to API Gateway with ASP.NET SDK

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to make a reques to API Gateway with the AWS SDK for .NET but I have no idea how to do that. The documentation is very lacking and there are no examples posted online of it.

This is as far as I've gotten so far:

```
const String awsAccessKeyId = "43789hf872hy832h"; // Get access key from a secure store
const String awsSecretAccessKey = "4738fbdhskjfy932hjk"; // Get secret key from a secure store
var client = new AmazonAPIGatewayClient(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey,RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

But I don't know how to make a get request to one of my APIs.

Does anyone have any experience dealing with this?

Comment: sure hope those aren't your real creds...

Comment: No they are not, just random numbers

Answer (score 2):

The [`AmazonApiGatewayClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/APIGateway/TAPIGatewayClient.html) isn't meant for invoking your API's, but rather a client for managing your ApiGateway resources.  If you would like to invoke your endpoints, you should be using an HTTP client for this.

[Here is one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient) you can use from within C#, but you can also use your browser, or a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).

Comment: I have tried doing that, but I get a 403 forbidden error when I try to add a filter query. I posted about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714765/making-request-to-aws-api-gateway-with-asp-net and haven't received an answer back